# Cargo complaning about unmatchable version requirements, even though matching versions exist

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cargo, version

I'm trying to run `anchor build` on a workspace and receiving errors about a supposedly unmatchable version requirement for the crate "time", even though matching versions exist locally:

[image: Output]

---

As far as I understand semantic versioning rules, all the candidate versions listed should actually meet the requirement. Am I wrong here or is something else going on?

Here's the Cargo.toml:

[image]

Building with `cargo build` works fine somehow.

---

- OS: Ubuntu v20.04 on WSL
- Anchor (avm): v0.25.0
- Anchor CLI: v0.24.2
- Solana CLI: v1.10.40

---

Steps I already tried to fix this include:

- Deleting the cargo cache
- Deleting the entire cargo registry
- Updating my solana and anchor distributions to the newest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely a bug due to the solana version: updating to 1.14 or later should fix it.

Somewhere around 1.11 there was an update to the way cargo-bpf is called, and cargo build-bpf is no longer the normal build toolpath.

When this is the issue, `cargo build` will work, but `anchor build` will not.

Note also that `solana-install update` can fail sometimes for major version updates, and you may just have reinstall with `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.14.10/install)"` (replace 1.14.10 with whatever is latest)